# Can't send ENTER key in Vim and ncurses apps under Byobu and Tmux

Tags: command-line, keyboard, vim, byobu, tmux

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 and got a strange problem with `byobu`, `tmux`, Vim and ncurses applications: <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't work, and I need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> instead.

For example, if I edit a file in Vim inside a Byobu (or Tmux) window in a Gnome-Terminal, typing <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't insert a newline character, but inserts a new line with a `M` character. To insert a new line I need to type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.
AS a result, to exit Vim I need to type <kbd>ESC</kbd> `:q` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

This happens also in ncurses applications such as `ncdu`: instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> I need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Changing the `TERM` environment variable seems to help, but not 100%. The default value I get in `byobu` and `tmux` is `TERM=screeen-256color`, but if I change it to `TERM=xterm-256color` everything seems to work fine in Vim, but not in `ncdu`.

In addition to this, <kbd>Enter</kbd> key doesn't work when I use <kbd>F9</kbd> to change Byobu configuration - as I said above, I need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to select items in the configuration.

I tried also to add the following line in both `~/.tmux.conf` and `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`, but it helped only with Vim:

`set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"`

The problem happens on `xterm` also.

How can I solve this?

#### Update

I tried again with a new user, and experienced the same problem, so my guess is that it could be something system-related.

#### Update 2

Tinkering around with `xev` I found that there's something odd with this laptop's keyboard - it's an ANSI keyboard even though I'm in Italy (standard Italian keyboard layouts are ISO), and  <kbd>Enter</kbd> **button sends the wrong keycode.**

When I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button it sends a kyecode 104, `KP_Enter`, instead of usual keycode 36, `Return`. So it's an hardware problem, perhaps unrelated to Ubuntu itself. Not sure why I didn't realise it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tinkering around with `xev` I found that <kbd>Enter</kbd> button on this keyboard sends the wrong keycode. I'm leaving here my findings and how I solved, so it can be useful to others.*

When I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button on this keyboard it sends a keycode 104, `KP_Enter`, instead of usual keycode 36, `Return`:

```
$ xev
...
KeyPress event, serial 47, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x7a5, subw 0x0, time 5065933, (762,538), root:(934,702),
    state 0x0, keycode 104 (keysym 0xff8d, KP_Enter), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
"   XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
...
```

So it's an hardware "problem", since `Return` and `KP_Enter` [are not the same](https://daringfireball.net/2020/07/return_and_enter) and [don't give always the same results](https://bugs.maemo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6009).

So to solve this problem I need to remap keycode 104 to `Return`. This can be don using `xmodmap` like this:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 104 = Return NoSymbol Return"
```

To make the change permanent, this command can be run at every login adding it to *"Startup Applications"*, like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the keyboard on my Evolve Maestro Ebook11 is the same way and this also fixes the problem for me. I stuck it in ~/.Xmodmap to load it automatically

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd. It is working outside tmux, yes?

Does it still happen if you run tmux without a config? Start a new tmux with `tmux -Ltest -f/dev/null new` and see if the problem exists with it too. If not then you will need to look at your config and see what it causing it.

The only other things I can think are to check if your terminal is actually sending C-m for Enter (you can run `cat` then press the key and see what is sent), or something to do with the `kent` capability in the terminfo entries. But they would be fiddly to test and why should they be wrong on Ubuntu anyway and just for you? Maybe try making sure your ncurses packages are up to date.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this after so much time - I didn't used that PC for a while because of current pandemic. Today I did a few tests and found that even a new user experience the same problem, so it mus be something system-related. I tried also running tmux as you suggested, with the same results.